# Poor query performance in MySQL

Tags: mysql-5.5, performance, windows, query-performance

I have a 10 million record table in a MySQL 5.5 InnoDB. It's running in a 16GB RAM server with good CPU and fast HD. When I run the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT knowledge_id, 
                tag_order, 
                tag_weight, 
                total_title_direct_words, 
                total_title_parenthesis_words, 
                tag_level 
FROM   knowledge_tags 
WHERE  ( tag_text = 'washington' ) 
       AND ( tag_level < 10 );
```

It will take around 9 seconds (first run) locally (localhost). The result count is 640. There is a Btree index for the fields 'tag_text, tag_level'. This query time isn't acceptable for what i want. What can I do?

Here is the EXPLAIN result:

```
1   SIMPLE  knowledge_tags  range   tags_by_word_text   tags_by_word_text   308 [null]  344 Using index condition; Using temporary
```

And the CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `knowledge_tags` (
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `knowledge_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dictionary_word_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_text` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_level` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `knowledge_family_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_weight` double DEFAULT '1',
  `total_title_direct_words` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_title_parenthesis_words` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`),
  KEY `tags_by_knowledge_id` (`knowledge_id`),
  KEY `tags_by_word_text` (`tag_text`,`tag_level`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tags_by_family_dictionary` (`knowledge_family_id`,`dictionary_word_id`,`tag_level`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tags_by_family_word_text` (`knowledge_family_id`,`tag_text`,`tag_level`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tags_by_dictionary` (`dictionary_word_id`,`tag_level`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3316 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: can you post `EXPLAIN` for this query(execution plan)

Comment: And the `CREATE TABLE` statement

Comment: Probably the solution is to create some huge index on the first 5 columns.

Comment: @ypercube added the CREATE statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add an index on all the columns used in the query, with this order (actually the order matters for the first 2 columns only, the rest 5 can be in any order within the index):

```
 (tag_text, 
  tag_level, 
  knowledge_id, tag_order, tag_weight, 
  total_title_direct_words, 
  total_title_parenthesis_words)
```

The query should then use this index for both the `WHERE` and the `DISTINCT` (or group by) part. You probably need to change the query slightly, removing the `DISTINCT` and using `GROUP BY` (this acts like a hint to the MySQL optimizer.)

```
SELECT   knowledge_id,                      -- remove DISTINCT
         tag_order, 
         tag_weight, 
         total_title_direct_words, 
         total_title_parenthesis_words, 
         tag_level 
FROM   knowledge_tags 
WHERE  ( tag_text = 'washington' ) 
  AND  ( tag_level < 10 )
GROUP BY   tag_text,                        -- use the same order
           tag_level,                       -- as in
           knowledge_id,                    -- the index,          
           tag_order,                       -- all
           tag_weight,                      -- the
           total_title_direct_words,        -- way
           total_title_parenthesis_words ;  -- down
```

The `EXPLAIN` should then show:

> Using where; Using index for group-by

If the result are good enough for your expectations, you can then drop the `tags_by_word_text` index.